# permission issue with docker under windows

Tags: windows, docker, permissions, chmod, docker-for-windows

I'm using this scheme :

1/ I'm working on windows 7

2/ I'm using vagrant to mount a "ubuntu/trusty64" box

3/ I apt-get install ansible

4/ I install docker and docker-compose with ansibe

5/ I create a docker image with this dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7-apache
MAINTAINER Bruno DA SILVA "bruno.dasilva@foo.com"

COPY containers-dirs-and-files/var/www/html/ /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

6/ I run it :

```
sudo docker build -t 10.100.200.200:5000/pimp-hello-world .
sudo docker run -p 80:80 -d --name test-php 10.100.200.200:5000/pimp-hello-world
```

7/ apache can't display the page, I have to add :

```
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html
```

to the dockerfile in order to have it visible.

so here is my question : can I handle files permission while working on windows (and how)?  Or do I have to move under linux?

Comment: I think that I found the solution : replacing the chmod by this chown :

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

Answer (score 1):

This happens in Linux. Docker copies the files and put root as owner. The only way I have found to overcome this without using chmod, is archiving the files in a tar file and then use

```
ADD content.tgz /var/www/html
```

It will expand automatically

Regards